# Using JQuery when and deferred returning undefined still

Tags: javascript, jquery-deferred, .when

I'm new to using `$.when` and `$.Deferred()`, and I can't seem to get them to work

What I'm trying to do is run a few functions, and when they've all finished trigger a final function

Here are a couple of options I've tried

Option 1 - Returning `d1.getRating is not a function` (this is a function further up in the script) following docs from [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) as I understood them

```
// Set Deferred
var d1 = $.Deferred();
// Return movie information
if (idResp[0].type === "movie") {
  // Output Slug
  traktSlug = 'movies/' + idResp[0].movie.ids.slug;
  // Output
  $.when(d1).done(function (ratingValue) {
      console.log('Rating Is: ' + ratingValue);
      outputIMDb(showCheckIn, traktSlug, ratingValue);
  });
  // Get Rating
  d1.getRating(idResp[0].type, idResp[0].movie.ids.trakt);
}
```

Option 2 - Returning `ratingValue is undefined`

```
// Return movie information
if (idResp[0].type === "movie") {
  // Output Slug
  traktSlug = 'movies/' + idResp[0].movie.ids.slug;
  // Output
  $.when(getRating(idResp[0].type, idResp[0].movie.ids.trakt)).done(function (ratingValue) {
      console.log('Rating Is: ' + ratingValue);
      outputIMDb(showCheckIn, traktSlug, ratingValue);
  });
}
```

Any suggestions or a nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated

Full source code can be [viewed on GitHub](https://github.com/dpDesignz/trakt-for-imdb/blob/master/js/main.js)

**UPDATE**

I realised after reading the [JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) again that `resolve()` is not the name of a generic function, so I modified my code, but I'm still getting `ratingValue is undefined` back

Updated Option 1 Code

```
// Set Deferred
var d1 = $.Deferred();
// Return movie information
if (idResp[0].type === "movie") {
  // Output Slug
  var traktSlug = 'movies/' + idResp[0].movie.ids.slug;
  // Output Div
  $.when(d1).done(function(ratingValue) {
      console.log('Rating Is: ' + ratingValue);
      outputIMDb(1, traktSlug, ratingValue);
  });
  // Get Rating
  d1.resolve(getRating(idResp[0].type, idResp[0].movie.ids.trakt));
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Sorry, my apologies for not including the `getRating` function. As follows

```
// Get Rating
function getRating(type, id, season = 0, episode =0) {
    var slugType = "";
    switch (type) {
        case "movie":
            slugType = "movies";
            break;
        default:
            slugType = "movies";
            break;
    }
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'https://api.trakt.tv/' + slugType + '/' + id + '/ratings');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setRequestHeader('trakt-api-version', '2');
    request.setRequestHeader('trakt-api-key', APP_KEY);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            // Get Response and put in array
            var ratingsResp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            // Return Rating
            return Math.round(ratingsResp.rating * 10);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
      };
      request.send();
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want to post your private API keys on github.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm new to github. How can I sync my code up without posting them? :-/

Comment: That being said, why do you use write `XMLHttpRequest()` code when you have jQuery? That doesn't make any sense at all. Use the jQuery Ajax functions.

Comment: @Tomalak that's the requirements by the API I'm using

Comment: The first thing to do is to delete your repo and reset your API keys. Then research how to do that. Articles have been written about that, you'll find a way.

Comment: No, that's absolutely not an API requirement. The Trakt API does not care whether you use jQuery on the client. No web API does.

Comment: I'm only going off the API docs examples they give at http://docs.trakt.apiary.io? I'm new to an API of this scale so I don't know what else to do. If you could point me in the right direction of doing it better like you say I would much appreciate it

Comment: Here is a pointer into the right direction. Complete rewrite of your code: http://pastebin.com/8BcBC3Ud, lightly annotated. Disclaimer: it's untested (I have no Trakt API key and did not want to create an account first), but it should work. Take some time to let it sink in, read about jQuery functions you don't recognize, step though it line-by-ine in the debugger to see how it works.

Comment: Additional notes: **1)** While jQuery `.clone()` can help with basic templating tasks, you should look into using a proper HTML templating library (handlebars or similar) if you plan to create full blocks of HTML on the client side. **2)** `ACC_TOK` is not really used in your code, I don't know what this is supposed to do. **3)** Read more examples on how jQuery deferreds (and promises in general) work.

Comment: A jQuery deferred object has no `.getRating()` method.  I don't know why you think it does.  So, your error is as expected.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was trying to call a function from further up.

Comment: Uhhh, `d1` is a jQuery deferred object.  That type of object doesn't have a `.getRating()` method.  Why would you think it does?  It appears to me like you need to go back to the drawing board and read a lot more about how a deferred or promise works.

Comment: Which is why I said I'm new to this and don't understand it and why I posted my example of what I've tried and where I got my info from. I thought this site was for helping people not shooting them down. I just need pointing in the right direction.

Comment: Honestly, this code is so far off that there is no simple fix we can put in an answer.  I'm trying to figure out what `getRating()` is and what you're trying to do with it.  I think I would need to see the `getRating()` code and to understand where you have asynchronous operations and for you to describe in words what you're trying to accomplish in order to know where to go next.  I could write a long list of things that are wrong with your current code in the question, but that won't provide a solution until we have more info.

Comment: Ohhh, and on this site, code that is important to the question should be pasted IN the question, not only available via an external link.  That is a site rule because external links have a habit of disappearing or changing, rendering the original question useless as a reference.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was thinking that might be the case. I spent a few hours last night researching but I think I ended up confusing myself. If you look at the second paragraph of my original question it explains what I'm trying to do, and just above my update is a link to the source file on github. Tomalak has very kindly rewritten my code which I will be looking at very closely tonight.

Comment: Your question is currently considered "off topic" here because the relevant `getRating()` code (and any other relevant async code) is not pasted into the question.

Comment: @jfriend00 I wasn't aware of that. Thanks. I'll update my question with the code when I can get access to a computer :-)

Comment: You had exactly zero comments to give on [my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940881/using-jquery-when-and-deferred-returning-undefined-still?noredirect=1#comment65239060_38940881)? Why?

Comment: @Tomalak I live in NZ and when you posted that to me I was going to bed. I've just come home from work and am only just getting a chance to look at it now. All my other replies today have been from a cellphone during my breaks. I really do appreciate what you did for me and I will be pouring over the code trying to understand it over the next couple of hours :)

Comment: Just making sure you did not simply overlook the comment and I did it all for naught. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak any reason you used `localStorage.getItem` over `chrome.storage.local.get`?

Comment: Yes, two. `localStorage` is [cross-browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage), and it is synchronous.

Comment: @Tomalak that would work great, except for the fact that `Local storage is per origin (per domain and protocol)`, and since my local storage is set from my background file, and then it's called on IMDb this doesn't work? Well I'm getting the alert come up anyway?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120947/discussion-between-tomalak-and-dpdesignz).

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to do is to write `getRating()` to return a promise. You could promisify `XMLHttpRequest()` but it's much easier to use `jQuery.ajax()`.

Here it is, based on the [original code on GitHub](https://github.com/dpDesignz/trakt-for-imdb/blob/master/js/main.js) :

```
function getRating(type, id, season=0, episode=0) { // mmm, formal defaults - odd for browser-based javascript.
    var slugType;
    switch(type) {
        case 'movie':
            slugType = 'movies';
        break;
        default:
            slugType = 'movies';
    }
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.trakt.tv/' + slugType + '/' + id + '/ratings',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'trakt-api-version': '2',
            'trakt-api-key': APP_KEY
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).then(function(response) {
        return Math.round(response.rating * 10);
    }).then(null, function(xhr, textMessage, errorThrown) {
        console.error('getRating error: ', textMessage);
        return $.when(0); // error recovery.
    });
}
```

Then, use `jQuery.ajax()` in the main routine too :

```
chrome.storage.local.get('access_token', function(result) {
    var ACC_TOK = result.access_token;
    if (ACC_TOK && typeof ACC_TOK !== undefined) {
        if (tabURL.includes('imdb.com')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.trakt.tv/search/imdb/' + tabURL.match(/tt\d{7}/),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'trakt-api-version': '2',
                    'trakt-api-key': APP_KEY
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            }).then(function(idResp) {
                if(idResp[0].type === 'movie') {
                    return getRating(idResp[0].type, idResp[0].movie.ids.trakt).then(function(ratingValue) {
                        console.log('Rating Is: ' + ratingValue);
                        outputIMDb(1, 'movies/' + idResp[0].movie.ids.slug, ratingValue);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("Type: " + idResp.type);
                }
            }).fail(function(xhr, textMessage, errorThrown) {
                console.error(textMessage);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Note that because `jQuery.ajax()` returns a promise, there's no need to generate/resolve your own `jQuery.Deferred()s`.

Code above may not be 100% correct but should go a considerable distance to a working solution.

Comment: Thanks heaps! I'll review this code tonight and see how I go. Much appreciate the help :-)

Comment: Are you purposely using ES6 constructs (default parameters) for browser-based code?  If so, you should probably explain that so the OP (who is somewhat of a beginner) does not get confused with that or isn't surprised when it doesn't work in some browsers.

Comment: @jfriend00, just repeating OP's own code, in that respect, despite its apparent absurdity.